# pymongo with flask

Tags: flask, pymongo

I am trying to return my posts, but instead I get

> TypeError: 'Cursor' object is not callable.

How can I correct this? Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask  
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo  
app = Flask(__name__)  
mongo = PyMongo(app)  
from pymongo import Connection  
connection = Connection()  
db = connection.test_database  
collection = db.test_collection  

@app.route('/')  
def home_page():  
   post = {"author":"mike","text":"jiii"}  
   posts = db.posts  
   posts.insert(post)  
   return posts.find()

if __name__=='__main__':  
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

find() returns a [Cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) object that you must iterate over to access the documents returned by the query.  As in:

```
for post in posts.find():
    # do something with post
```

Answer (score 7):

When you return something from a Flask handler it must be one of the following types of things:

- A [`flask.Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Response) object (or a [`werkzeug.wrappers.Response`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Response) object). Using Flask's [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template) will return a response object.
- A tuple in the form [`(content, status_code, headers)`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.make_response)
- A WSGI callable (A function or callable object that takes two params and returns an iterable).

When you return the PyMongo `Cursor` object Flask sees that it is not an instance of [`flask.Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Response) (actually, [`flask.Flask.response_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.response_class)) and not a tuple so it assumes that it must be a WSGI object and attempts to call it (hence the error).

The best solution is to either use [`flask.jsonfiy`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.jsonify) to return a JSON response or to [create a template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#rendering-templates) to render the posts and use [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template) to return the appropriate response.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are both correct. Flask views are expected to return some kind of HTTP response. So you need to process the data and make a response, probably using Flask’s utility functions. Also, the `find()` method returns a cursor, that you need to iterate over at some point.

You just need to change the last line of the view:

```
@app.route('/')  
def home_page():  
   post = {"author":"mike","text":"jiii"}  
   posts = db.posts  
   posts.insert(post)  
   return render_template(posts.find(), "index.html")
```

And provide an `index.html` that contains something like:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<h2>Post by {{ post.author}}</h2>
<p>{{ post.text }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from flask_pymongo import Pymongo
```

instead of:

```
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
```